# Date comparison in JSP

Tags: java, html, sql, jsp, date

I have 3 combobox defines date, month and year which user will input

```
<select name="date" style="width:inherit">
<%for(i=1;i<32;i++){%>
<option value="<%=i%>"><%=i%></option>
<%}%>
</select>
<span>
<span style="width:50%">
<select name="month" style="width:inherit">

<option value="01">January</option>
<option value="02">February</option>
<option value="03">March</option>
<option value="04">April</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">June</option>
<option value="07">July</option>
<option value="08">August</option>
<option value="09">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>

</select>
</span>

<span style="width:24%">
<select name="year" style="width:inherit">
<%for(i=2000;i<2015;i++){%>
<option value="<%=i%>"><%=i%></option>
<%}%>
</select>
```

After that, the form post to `doinsert.jsp` and try to compare user input's date and today's date. If user input's date before today the variable `isPast` should be <0. However, when I try to input Dec 20,2013 (today is Dec 21,2013) the variable `isPast` is -1 which is right. When I try to input Dec 25,2013 (today is Dec 21,2013) the variable `isPast` is still -1 which is wrong (should be 1). When I try to input Jan 1,2014 (today is Dec 21,2013) the variable `isPast` is 1 which is right. I have the following code in doinsert.jsp:

```
    String date=request.getParameter("date");
    String month=request.getParameter("month");
    String year=request.getParameter("year");

    String concatdate=year+"-"+month+"-"+date;
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    java.sql.Date newdate= new java.sql.Date(ft.parse(concatdate).getTime());
    java.util.Date now=new java.util.Date();
    int isPast=0;
    isPast=newdate.compareTo(now);
```

What's wrong? Is there any mismatch date format between `newdate` and `now`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strip the time part from the **now** date.

Your parsing pattern is wrong: yyyy-mm-dd.
It should be yyyy-MM-dd.

The types of your two dates are different too.
You do all this in a pretty complex way.
Do not use **java.sql.Date**, you don't need it.

Just use **java.util.Date** and this method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29

The **java.util.Date** class already has what you need.

And for stripping the time part you may use something like this.

```
public static Date removeTime(Date date) {
    if (date == null)
        return null;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Good answer, after stripping the time, the dates can be compared

Comment: still get <0 if I input Dec 25,2013

Comment: @noobprogrammer This is also wrong "yyyy-mm-dd" should be "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: thanks @peter.petrov it's only 2 characters mistake -_-

Comment: @noobprogrammer Usually it is like this :)